# Does AutoCompletionExtender Method of AJAX Control Toolkit have to be static?

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have web page which is using AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtener on some TextBox.
This extender requires service method, from which it will get data to display:

`[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList2(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
        {
            return DatabaseSearch.GetUnits().GetSymbolCompletion(prefixText, organizationToSearch);
        }`

In this method I use some argument = organizationToSearch. But I don't want this argument to be static ! And since the method is static I don't know what to do. If I remove the 'static' keyword from method definition it won't work... And I really don't want change organizationToSearch to static either!

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It must be static 'cause you're not in the execution of your page. When you're calling an AjaxMethod, your page (webforms) doesn't exists.

Comment: So, is there a way to use non-static variables inside of this method?

Comment: You have to add it in your method's parameters

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you are in a completly new request and not in the execution of your page anymore (your page has already rendered by this stage)..

You will need to transfer and parameters out and pass them back into the static method..